# How to get select-string to pipe to substring

Tags: powershell

I want to pull out a string from a txt file that shows how fast my SQL Server backups run.  This shows me the line that contains the information:

```
Select-String -Path "DatabaseBackup - USER_DATABASES - FULL*.txt" -pattern "MB/sec"
```

The problem is that the line of text is over 2000 characters so I want to pipe it to substring to grab just a portion.  Unfortunately, this code:

```
Select-String -Path "DatabaseBackup - USER_DATABASES - FULL*.txt" -pattern "MB/sec" | ForEach-Object { $_.substring(42,30) }
```

gives

> Method invocation failed because [Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.MatchInfo] does not contain a method named 'substring'.

Any hints on how to get this working?

Ken

[Edit] The solution is provided by JosefZ.  For my own future reference, the database names are enclosed with single quotes and the speed is enclosed in open and close round brackets.  This code:

```
Select-String -Path "DatabaseBackup - USER_DATABASES - FULL*.txt" -pattern "MB/sec" | 
ForEach-Object {
    $_.Line.substring($_.Line.IndexOf(''''), $_.Line.IndexOf('''', $_.Line.IndexOf('''')+1)-$_.Line.IndexOf('''')+1) + "    " + $_.Line.substring($_.Line.IndexOf('('),$_.Line.IndexOf(')')-$_.Line.IndexOf('(')+1)
}
```

produces output that looks like:

```
'DBA'    (796.230 MB/sec)  
'ReportServer'    (488.596 MB/sec) 
'ReportServerTempDB'    (139.270 MB/sec)
'TSTGP'    (420.375 MB/sec)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Select-String](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-string): *By default, the output is a set of `MatchInfo` objects with one for each match found.*

Apply `.substring` method to the `$_.Line` string, e.g. as follows:

```
Select-String -Path "DatabaseBackup - USER_DATABASES - FULL*.txt" -pattern "MB/sec" |
    ForEach-Object { $_.Line.substring(42,30) }
```

Comment: indeed. The alternative in PowerShell (Core) 7+ is to use `Select-String`'s `-Raw` switch, which results in only the matching lines getting output (as strings) to begin with; that is, the original `ForEach-Object { $_.substring(42,30) }` would then work.

Answer (score -1):

[`Select-String`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.powershell.commands.matchinfo?view=powershellsdk-7.2.0) is returning a `MatchInfo` object so you would need to iterate over the `Matches` property of that object.

So you could do something like this:

```
(Select-String -Path "DatabaseBackup - USER_DATABASES - FULL*.txt" -pattern "MB/sec").Matches | 
ForEach-Object { $_.substring(42,30) }
```

Comment: This also gives:  Method invocation failed because [System.Text.RegularExpressions.Match] does not contain a method named 'substring'.

Comment: `.Matches` contains only the matching part(s) of the line, not the line as a whole, and is the latter that is of interest here. Aside from that, `.Matches` contains a collection of `Match` instances that each have a `.Value` property containing a matched string. Thus, you cannot call `.Substring()` directly on `.Matches`; however - via member-access enumeration - you can call it on `.Matches.Value`; e.g.: `('foo' | Select-String  oo).Matches.Value | ForEach-Object { $_.Substring(1) }`